# How to run patched iOS binary file after

Tags: ios, code-signing, jailbreak, ipa, penetration-testing

I have need to bypass JailBreak detection in iOS application, for pt.  I have patched/changed its few related parts e.g. where it is detecting cydia etc. And uploaded back to the iDevice to found that it is crashing.

Do I need to sign it-- even on Jailbroken phone? if so can I self sign it?

Or I am doing something else wrong?

Will appreciate your views

Comment: patched mean changing in HexEditor

Comment: Is it AppStore app? Is it been cracked (decrypted)?

Comment: It is not an AppStore app yet and It is not encrypted

Comment: But it's ipa which means signature checks are still in place. You either have to resign the app with valid developer/enterprise certificate or install AppSync from cydia to disable signature checks for IPA apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to re-sign it.

All iOS apps must be signed with an Apple issued cert on iOS.

On the iOS device, the user must also have selected  `\Settings\General\Profiles & Device Management\` for the Developer Cert to be trusted.

Re-signing a patched iOS binary (the iPA file) can be achieved a number of ways.  Try this as a starting point:  https://github.com/nowsecure/node-applesign/wiki

Since xCode 7 you could get a free developer cert to sign app bundles and frameworks.  This free account works fine for patching and re-signing app.

As a sidenote:  the same rule do not quite apply to Android. You must sign the Android app (the APK file).  But a self-signed APK will work if the device has `Allow Sideloaded App = true`.